# Increase head rule width in exam class

Tags: exam

I'm working in the exam class, and I have `\firstpageheadrule` in my code.

If I were using `\fancyhdr` I would use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2cm}`.

How can I do this in the exam class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule in the `exam` class is not customizable, other than on/off. But you don't have to use their headers, I think you can use `fancyhdr` with some precaution, because `exam.cls` has a couple of commands in common with `fancyhdr`, such as `\lhead`. These must be eliminated before loading `fancyhdr`.

So if you want to try `fancyhdr`, try this:

```
\let\lhead\relax\let\chead\relax\let\rhead\relax
\let\lfoot\relax\let\cfoot\relax\let\rfoot\relax
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
```

You must take into account that `exam.cls` makes different headers on cover pages, first page and following pages.

If you don't want to use `fancyhdr`, or if you find that it still clashes with `exam.cls`, you can patch the command that generates the headrule.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fullhead}
{\hrule}{\hrule height 2pt}{}{ERROR}
\makeatother
```

Replace the `2pt` with your desired thickness.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second solution which worked straight away. Would it be possible to change the colour of the line, or would I have to use `\rule` since it's treated as a character? Maybe changing the colour will be easier if I use the first solution

Comment: Ok, I figured out what `\patchcmd` does, and so found a solution to my second question:  

`{\hrule}{{\color{red}{\hrule height 2pt}}}{}{ERROR}`